# How to sum and rank multiple occurrences in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically, I have a list of names and values in two columns, respectively.

[image: Kind of like this]

But they are listed according to date, like a logbook (hence the random order and multiple occurrences of names).  I want to know if it is possible to automatically sum up each person's items in another column and then rank them?

I'm not knowledgeable with Excel formulas much so a step-by-step instruction and or brief explanation of the content of the code (assuming that it would be extensive and complicated) would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

The image I posted was just an example. The real thing is actually a long list and there are at least 50 different names in it and the log keeps adding up new entries. The idea is to get the top 5 people who have the highest amount of items.

In order to do that, I'd have to get the total score/sum of items each person has to be able to rank them. But with the amount of entries, it'll take a lot of time. So if there's an excel formula to automatically give me such results that would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Just to clarify, by sum, you mean that, for example, John would show a total of 4?  How are you envisioning ranking them?  Just sorting the results in descending order by sum, or adding another column to assign a numerical rank to each name (1 = largest sum)?  How do you rank tie scores?

Comment: I expect [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) will do the job of summing based on name for you - I'd think that ranking the results should be pretty easy too, by applying a filter to the column holding the sums.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, that's what I meant by sum. By ranking them I meant assigning a numerical rank (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.,) As for tied scores maybe on the same rank? It doesn't really matter much. My only concern is if for example I wanted to only get the top 5 people (arranged according to whoever has the highest score, if there's a tie in let's say, the 3rd place then there will be two people in the 3rd place I suppose) out of 50 people on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right Sumif and Rank should give the result.
First write the names without duplicate in another column starting D2 for example and in E2 write the formula =SUMIF($A$2:$A$11,D2,$B$2:$B$11) exactly, where A11 is the last name with duplicates and B11 the last item then drag it down in front of each name. After calculating the totals make another column for rank in F2 write the formula =RANK(E2,$E$2:$E$5) where E5 is the last calculated total and you can drag it also it will give you the descending order without sort.

Comment: This would probably do if I only have a few names on the list, like the one on the example I gave. But I have like at least 50 names and counting (like a logbook as I've mentioned) so it might be counterproductive if I have to rewrite names without duplicates on a different column. I understand how the filters work however it doesn't really help when I have to find each person's score and only get the top 5 from the list. I'm trying to find out if there's actually a way to easily calculate the total score/items of each person without having to filter every time and then automatically rank them

Comment: Just copy all the names and paste it in another column then remove duplicates you don't have to write it again.